# Can i sleep in my boxer shirts? Is it haram if my sister see me in my underwear?

Tags: halal-haram, clothing, family

I live in Asia. I am a Muslim and it is very hot in our country. I sleep in my boxer shorts everyday. I also roam around like this in the daylight . My mom and my sister are comfortable they don't feel anything. I just want to ask that is it a sin or is it haram that my sister sees me where my private parts are covered, but my legs are revealed above the knees. I am also shirtless. Is this allowed in Islam

Comment: The thigh is 'awrah according to the majority view. Following that you shouldn't let any man see it, let alone a woman even if she is a mahram.

Answer (score -1):

The Awrah of a man in front of his mother and sisters is his private parts (penis and anus), strictly-speaking. The "izaar" i.e. loincloth that Arabs of 7th century used for covering private parts, roughly extended from navel to knees. Navel and knees itself are not private parts. So it is lawful for a man to wear boxers, underwear, swim shorts etc. in front of his mother and sisters, provided that it is thick enough not to reveal skin colour.

Answer (score -2):

Mother and sister are mahram so covering your awrah is not an obligation.so there is risk of fitnah and desire  as they are forbidden for u to marriage....
“…and not to reveal their adornment except to their husbands, or their fathers, or their husband’s fathers, or their sons, or their husband’s sons, or their brothers or their brother’s sons, or their sister’s sons, or their (Muslim) women (i.e. their sisters in Islam)…”
[al-Noor 24:31]
Btw i am also shirtless most of the time coz of heat xD

Comment: So what should I do? What's your answer Yes or no?